# How to remove duplicate array values in react class component

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, duplicates, frontend

I have a react class component displaying array of objects. However, when i render to display the data i get duplicate data. How can i remove the duplicates.

```
Customer.js

    this.state = {
          customer:[
           { id: 1, createdAt: "2023-01-22T05:19:45.943Z" },
           { id: 1, createdAt: "2023-01-19T02:19:45.943Z" },
           { id: 2, createdAt: "2023-01-18T05:30:45.943Z" },
          ],
        };

    componentDidMount() {
      axios
        .get("http://localhost:4000/customer/show", {
          responseType: "json"
        })
        .then(response => {
          
          this.setState({ customer: response.data });
        });
    }

.....................................
  render() {
  return(
     {
        this.state.customer?.map((item) => {
            return (
            <div>
              <div key={ item.id }> Time of Visit: {moment(item.createdAt).format('hh:mm A')} 
              </div>
            </div>
            );
         })
     })}
```

Output

Time of Visit: 5:19 PM
Time of Visit: 2:19 PM

Time of Visit: 5:30 PM
Time of Visit: 5:30 PM

When i render the array of objects i get duplicate values. How can i change this code to display only unique values. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the data and by what yardstick do you measure duplicateness?

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen have added the data and output. The problem is that id 2 is duplicated twice, while id 1 data is displayed correctly as two objects.

Comment: Side note: _highly_ recommend against using filter in render. There are other react hooks that will be better suited…`.filter()` creates a new array every time. depending on the app it can really lead to performance issues, since every render could cause a rerender of its children

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Dom. Performance-wise `map()` has the potential to be even worse. `filter()` creates a shallow copy whereas `map()` creates a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way to filter out the repetitive value:

```
const ids = demoArray.map((d) => d.id)
const filteredResponse = demoArray.filter(
    ({ id }, index) => !ids.includes(id, index + 1)
```

So with your code it should be like this:

```
this.state = {
  customer:[
   { id: 1, createdAt: "2023-01-22T05:19:45.943Z" },
   { id: 1, createdAt: "2023-01-19T02:19:45.943Z" },
   { id: 2, createdAt: "2023-01-18T05:30:45.943Z" },
  ],
};

componentDidMount() {
axios
.get("http://localhost:4000/customer/show", {
  responseType: "json"
})
.then(response => {
  const ids = response.data.map((d) => d.id)
  const filteredResponse = response.data.filter(
({ id }, index) => !ids.includes(id, index + 1)
)
  
  this.setState({ customer: filteredResponse });
});
}

render() {
return(
  {this.state.customer?.map((item) =>  (
    <div>
      <div key={ item.id }> Time of Visit: 
        {moment(item.createdAt).format('hh:mm A')} 
      </div>
    </div>
    )
 )
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array filter function to customize your output.

```js
function filterToGetEachIdOnce(item, index) {
    return customer.findIndex(customer => customer.id === item.id) === index)
}

render() {
  const { customer = [] } = this.state

  return customer
         .filter(filterToGetEachIdOnce)
         .map((item) => {
            return (
            <div>
              <div key={ item.id }> Time of Visit: {moment(item.createdAt).format('hh:mm A')} 
              </div>
            </div>
            );
         })
     })}
```

I have extracted the filter function to make it clear that you can modify it as you wish.

Check out the following links for more information:

- [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)